# Why is @ referring to Window object in Coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

Having a bit of hardtime understanding coffeescript. Why is this the window object in the set_position function?

```
window.App = {}

$ ->
  driver = new Driver if ($('#drivers_become').length >= 1)
  window.App.driver = driver

class Driver
  constructor: ->
    @get_position()
  get_position: ->
    if navigator.geolocation
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(@set_position)
  set_position: (pos) ->
    # this refers to window object in this case. why?
    @latitude = pos.coords.latitude
    @longitude = pos.coords.longitude
  get_latitude: ->
    @latitude
  get_longitude: ->
    @longitude
```

get_latitude and get_longitude return undefined in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic binding issue, and applies as much to Javascript as Coffeescript.

You are passing a `Driver` method, `set_position` to a Windows function,

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(@set_position)
```

That function evaluates `set_position` in the global, windows, context.  In effect it ends up setting global `latitude` and `longitude` variables, not the attributes of the `Driver` instance.  In your console see if those variables are defined.

What you want to do is define `set_position` so `@`is bound to the `Driver` instance.  To do that, use the fat arrow, `=>`.  http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow

```
set_position: (pos) =>
    # this refers to window object in this case. why?
    @latitude = pos.coords.latitude
    @longitude = pos.coords.longitude
```

If you use this, and look at the compiled Coffee, you will see a line that does:

```
this.set_position = __bind(this.set_position, this);
```

Packages like jquery and underscore also have a `bind` function, as do recent browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

```
get_position: ->
   if navigator.geolocation
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(@set_position.bind(this))
```

Uses the browser's `bind`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `aDriverInstance.set_position` as an event handler function, the browser will invoke it as a regular function not a method. To fix that, use a "fat arrow" when defining it: `set_position: (pos) =>`. But more broadly it is a question of invoking via dot notation and invoking via direct reference:

`aDriverInstance.set_position(pos)` will have `this` set to `aDriverInstance` and all is well

`set_position_reference = aDriverInstance.set_position;set_position_reference(pos)` will have `this` set to the window object.